# Laravel, need show route url domen/specialist/id

Tags: php, laravel

I want show domen url user id after signin, example domen/specialist/id.
ALREADY AS DAY 2 IT IS NOT RECEIVED TO DO. Maybe I'm doing something wrong help please.

This my web.php code

```
 // Front End Routes
 Route::group([
 'namespace' => 'landing',
 'middleware' => 'groups',
 ], function (){
 Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index')->name('landing.index');
 Route::get('/specialist/{id}', 'SpecialistDashboardController@dashboard')- 
 >name('frontend.specialist.dashboard');
 Route::get('/logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');
});
```

Specialist Dashboard Controller code

```
class SpecialistDashboardController extends Controller
{

    public function dashboard($id){
        $id = Auth::user()->id;
        return view('Frontend.specialists.dashboard.index');
    }

    public function profile_settings(){
        return view('Frontend.specialists.profile_settings.index');
    }
}
```

GroupsMiddleware

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // ADMIN = 5
        if (\Auth::check() && Auth::user()->groups == 5){
            return $next($request);
        }
        // PATIENTS = 1
        elseif(\Auth::check() && Auth::user()->groups == 1){
            return redirect()->route('landing.index');
        }
        // SPECIALISTS = 3
        elseif (\Auth::check() && Auth::user()->groups == 3){
            return redirect()->route('frontend.specialist.dashboard');
        }
    }
```

Error message: 
Missing required parameters for [Route: frontend.specialist.dashboard] [URI: specialist/{id}].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `frontend.specialist.dashboard` route requires a `id` paramter but you didn't provide any when redirecting. Also looking at your `SpecialistDashboardController`, the `$id` can be omitted since you're overwriting it with `Auth::id()`.

Try doing this:

```php
# remove the {id} param
Route::get('/specialist', 'SpecialistDashboardController@dashboard')- 
 >name('frontend.specialist.dashboard');
```

```php
class SpecialistDashboardController extends Controller
{
    ...
    public function dashboard(){ // remove the $id param
        $id = Auth::user()->id;
        return view('Frontend.specialists.dashboard.index');
    }
    ...
}
```

But if in any case you need the id param, you can provide the value for it in redirect by doing

```php
return redirect()->route('frontend.specialist.dashboard', ['id' => $id]);
```

Comment: if I take off what you indicated. How will the id appear?

Comment: I don't see you using the `$id` in your sample. since your getting the authenticated user's id (`Auth::user()->id` can also be used as `Auth::id()`)